# Pandas: change data type of Series to String

Tags: python, pandas, series

I use Pandas 'ver 0.12.0' with Python 2.7 and have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [123,512,'zhub1', 12354.3, 129, 753, 295, 610],
                    'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                            'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular']
                    },  columns= ['id','colour', 'shape'])
```

The `id` Series consists of some integers and strings. Its `dtype` by default is `object`. I want to convert all contents of `id` to strings. I tried `astype(str)`, which produces the output below.

```
df['id'].astype(str)
0    1
1    5
2    z
3    1
4    1
5    7
6    2
7    6
```

**1)** How can I convert all elements of `id` to String?

**2)** I will eventually use `id` for indexing for dataframes. Would having String indices in a dataframe slow things down, compared to having an integer index?

Comment: Not sure why you get that output as `astype` works fine for me, at least in version 0.13.1, maybe 0.12.0 has a bug? In answer to your second point, yes it is likely to be slower as string comparison will not be faster than integer comparison but I would profile this first, also it depends on the size

Comment: you've set the column, right? df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)

Comment: @Andy Hayden, yes I do the appointment, but it is the output that I thought was unexpected.

Comment: unexpected in what way?

Comment: It only returns the 1st character of each Series element as I put in the question under `df['id'].astype(str)`

Comment: For anyone wondering why the accepted answer isn't working in later versions of pandas, I have added a new answer to the question to reflect the current documentation.

Comment: @Zhubarb, please change the accepted answer

Answer (score 232, accepted):

A new answer to reflect the most current practices: as of now (v1.2.4), neither `astype('str')` nor `astype(str)` work.

[As per the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html), a Series can be converted to the string datatype in the following ways:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype("string")

df['id'] = pandas.Series(df['id'], dtype="string")

df['id'] = pandas.Series(df['id'], dtype=pandas.StringDtype)
```

Comment: When i try this I get `data type "string" not understood`

Comment: First solution works technically, but replaces content. Copies the strings of one row into all others. particular. Second solution doesn't work technically. Third throws error ```TypeError: Expected an instance of StringDtype, but got the class instead. Try instantiating 'dtype'.``` Will look at specifying data type when I load the data.

Comment: The third solution misses brackets. The following worked ```df['col'] = pandas.Series(df['col'], dtype = pd.StringDtype())
 ```

Answer (score 125):

You can convert all elements of id to `str` using `apply`

```
df.id.apply(str)

0        123
1        512
2      zhub1
3    12354.3
4        129
5        753
6        295
7        610
```

**Edit by OP:**

I think the issue was related to the Python version (2.7.), this worked:

```
df['id'].astype(basestring)
0        123
1        512
2      zhub1
3    12354.3
4        129
5        753
6        295
7        610
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I am next to a computer and accept your answer. do you know why `astype(str )` does not work?

Comment: @Zhubarb - I just tried it, I am getting same result with `df['id'].astype(str)`

Comment: the same result that I posted (undesired) or the result that you got  with `df.id.apply(str)` (desired)?

Comment: I believe it should be `.astype('str')` instead of `.astype(str)`

Comment: I just tried with `df['id'].astype(str)` and I am getting SettingWithCopyWarning: warning. How to get rid of this warning?

Comment: @ErnestSKirubakaran - Read the previous comment, try with `.astype('str')`

Comment: I'm trying the df['id'].astype(basestring) and I'm receiving an error NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined.

Comment: Also I believe `apply` isn’t really vectorized way of converting to str.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated, as the type to specify is now `"string"` and`'str'` is no longer accepted

Answer (score 70):

You must assign it, like this:-

```
df['id']= df['id'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 8):

Personally none of the above worked for me. 
What did:

```
new_str = [str(x) for x in old_obj][0]
```

Comment: Ya true the other ones did not change anything. I know those should've worked but something is off and it did not so I guess this can also be a solution

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
df.loc[:,'id'] = df.loc[:, 'id'].astype(str)
```

This is why they recommend this solution:  [Pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

TD;LR

To reflect some of the answers:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype("string")
```

This will break on the given example because it will try to convert to [StringArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.StringArray.html#pandas.arrays.StringArray) which can not handle any number in the 'string'.

```
df['id']= df['id'].astype(str)
```

For me this solution throw some warning:

```
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities:

- Use `.astype("str").astype("string")`. As seen [here](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-featurestore/sagemaker_featurestore_fraud_detection_python_sdk.html#Ingest-Data-into-FeatureStore)
- Use `.astype(pd.StringDtype())`. From the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked:

```
 df['id'].convert_dtypes()
```

see the documentation here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html

Answer (score 2):

use pandas string methods ie `df['id'].str.cat()`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do dynamically

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can easily be solved by converting it to the object first. After it is converted to object, just use "astype" to convert it to str.

```
obj = lambda x:x[1:]
df['id']=df['id'].apply(obj).astype('str')
```

Answer (score -2):

for me .to_string() worked

```
df['id']=df['id'].to_string()
```