# Python Float to Int Conversion Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer

I'm pretty new to python.  My goal is to change a float into an int.  The float is a series.  There are no Nans.  I've checked out quite a few posts, including: [Pandas: change data type of Series to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231592/pandas-change-data-type-of-series-to-string).

i've tried a few different types of syntax:

````
```comp.month.apply(int)```
````

Here's the error that followed that.

````
```TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-190-690a8228abec> in <module>()
----> 1 comp.month.apply(int)
/Users/halliebregman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
2058             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
----> 2060         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
2061         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
2062             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:58435)()
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable```
````

and also:

````
```with open ("ints.csv", "w") as ints:
    for i in range(len(comp)):
        months = int(comp['month'][i])
        days = int(comp['day'][i])
        print months, days
        ints.write('{} {} \n'.format(months, days))```
````

Followed by this error:

````
```TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-191-0d6fe0a99830> in <module>()  
1 with open ("ints.csv", "w") as ints:
2     for i in range(len(comp)):
----> 3         months = int(comp['month'][i])
4         days = int(comp['day'][i])
5         print months, days
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable```
````

What am I missing here?  It seems like this should be simple :/

Thanks!

Comment: What does `print type(int)` show? Have you accidentally shadowed the `int` builtin with a file object?

Comment: `<type 'file'>`  yes it appears that way.  how do i change it back?!

Comment: For an immediate fix, try `del int`. But you should look back and figure out where you assigned to `int` in the first place, and remove that assignment.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: Accidentally shadowing `int`? This is the stuff of debugging nightmares, nice catch @MarkDickinson