# Python/Pandas - Convert type from pandas period to string

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have a DataFrame:

```
         Seasonal
Date             
2014-12 -1.089744
2015-01 -0.283654
2015-02  0.158974
2015-03  0.461538
```

I used a pd.to_period in the DataFrame, so its index has turned into a Pandas period type (type 'pandas._period.Period').

Now, I want to turn that index to strings. I'm trying to apply the following:

```
df.index=df.index.astype(str)
```

However that doesn't work...

```
ValueError: Cannot cast PeriodIndex to dtype |S0
```

My code has been frozen since then.

S.O.S.

Comment: Will `df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')` work for you?

Comment: add this as an answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then convert to `string`:

```
print df

#        Seasonal
#Date             
#2014-12 -1.089744
#2015-01 -0.283654
#2015-02  0.158974
#2015-03  0.461538

print df.index

#PeriodIndex(['2014-12', '2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03'],
#              dtype='int64', name=u'Date', freq='M')

df.index=df.index.to_series().astype(str)
print df

#         Seasonal
#Date             
#2014-12 -1.089744
#2015-01 -0.283654
#2015-02  0.158974
#2015-03  0.461538

print df.index

#Index([u'2014-12', u'2015-01', u'2015-02', u'2015-03'], dtype='object', name=u'Date')
```

Answer (score 9):

The line below should convert your `PeriodIndex` to string format:

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the items to strings by specifying `basestring`:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(basestring)
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
df.index = df.index.map(str)
```

Refering to the comments from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22231860/2568763), it might have to do with your pandas/python version.

Answer (score 1):

If your index is a `PeriodIndex`, you can convert it to a `str` `list` as the following example shows:

```
import pandas as pd
pi = pd.period_range("2000-01", "2000-12", freq = "M")
print(list(pi.astype(str)))
```