# Pandas replace a character in all column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames with column names (coming from .csv files) containing `(` and `)` and I'd like to replace them with `_`.

How can I do that in place for all columns?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[()]", "_", regex=True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'(A)':[1,2,3],
                   '(B)':[4,5,6],
                   'C)':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   (A)  (B)  C)
0    1    4   7
1    2    5   8
2    3    6   9

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[()]", "_", regex=True)
print (df)
   _A_  _B_  C_
0    1    4   7
1    2    5   8
2    3    6   9
```

Comment: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`

Comment: @Seymour It means some or all numeric columns, so need `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.replace("[()]", "_")`

Comment: you are right. Actually the columns are output of `PeriodIndex` and their type is `pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex`. Any idea of how to obtain the same column name but in a string?

Comment: @Seymour - I think need check [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34800343).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Just curious about why the`'[ ]'`for the `"[()]"` part? I tried it and it doesn't work. Could you tell me what `[ ]` does in this case please?

Comment: @BowenLiu - It means [regex](https://regexone.com/lesson/matching_characters) for matching only `()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've seen people writing short and elegant regex that can perform complex tasks. I am trying to learn it. However, there are so many tutorials out there and I got confused. Is the link you gave a good source to read up on the topic?

Comment: I find it odd that you don't have to explicitly specify that you're supplying a regex. Seems like that could complicate things for beginners, though I guess there is an `regex` parameter that you can explicitly set to `False` if you're attempting simple pattern replacements.

Comment: To use this with a regex, I needed `regex=True` passed too. It is defaulting to `False` in [latest versions of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Answer (score 4):

Older pandas versions don't work with the accepted answer above. Something like this is needed:

```
df.columns = [c.replace("[()]", "_") for c in list(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are used to demarcate a range of characters you want extracted. for example:

```
r"[Nn]ational"
```

will extract both occurences where we have "National" and "national" i.e it extracts N or n.