# How do I convert Pandas DateTime Quarter object into string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I did some pivoting and got column headers formatted as datetime objects, more precisely as periods, looking like this Period('2000Q1', 'Q-DEC'). Now how could I convert this period back into a string i.e. for the above just '2000Q1'?

realized this is a possible duplication of: [Python/Pandas - Convert type from pandas period to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800343/python-pandas-convert-type-from-pandas-period-to-string)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `str()` on it

```
>> p = pd.Period('2001Q1')
>> str(p)
'2001Q1'
```