# Converting zipcodes to states in python

Tags: python, zipcode

I am trying to convert all of the zip codes in a 'zip_code" column into states using zipcode 2.0.0 package.

```
zip=f['zip_code']
zip=zip.astype(int)
zip=zip.astype(str)
for i in zip:
    myzip = zipcode.isequal(i)
    print(myzip.state)
```

I have converted the zip codes to string because myzip accepts strings only. However, when I try to print out the corresponding states, it gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state'
```

What is the problem here? Package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zipcode)

Comment: `zip` is a reserved keyword in python; please use something else.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, technically, `zip` is not a keyword, but a built-in function. Still a reserved name that OP should avoid using for his variables.

Comment: @brddawg I mean, possibly. We don't know what `f['zip_code']` is and `astype` might be a lift of `str` to operate on a collection of some zipcode-like object.

Comment: @datalearner your input method and sample data would help.

Comment: @Adam Smith just found a few issues with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231592/pandas-change-data-type-of-series-to-string - either zip.astype(basestring) or zip.apply(str) should work shown in the answer.

Comment: @brddawg why do you think `f` is a pandas array?

Comment: @AdamSmith good point - results in searching for that method on so returned pandas & nymph with pandas being the most common. good tag to add.

Comment: `zip` is not *reserved*, which would imply one *cannot* reuse it. It is simply predefined, meaning one *should* not reuse it without understanding the consequences. `class` is an example of a reserved keyword, which is why one uses something like `cls` as the conventional first argument to a class method.

Comment: What is `f`? Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve] in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to here: http://pythonhosted.org/zipcode/, the `isequal` method can return a Zip object or None if the zipcodes are not equal. Therefore you should only print the state if you get back a valid zipcode. Try this:

```
zip=f['zip_code']
zip=zip.astype(int)
zip=zip.astype(str)
for i in zip:
    myzip = zipcode.isequal(i)
    if myzip:
        print(myzip.state)
```

Comment: That was quick! Thank you, you solved the problem:) I guess I have a long to way go when it comes to finding answers before posting a question.

Comment: No worries! Tick the green tick next to the answer if it worked for you.