# Writing series to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a long matrix (say A) with 10,000 rows and 2 columns in an excel file.

I need to copy each column in separate text files (say A0.txt, A1.txt);

I did the following

```
A0 = open("A0.txt", "w+")
A1 = open("A1.txt", "w+")
A0.write(A.iloc[:,0])
A1.write(A.iloc[:,1])
```

but the error is

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series

then, how can I write the series?

Comment: Take a look t this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231592/pandas-change-data-type-of-series-to-string .

Comment: alternatively, you can try numpy np.savetxt('A0.txt', a.iloc[:,0].values, delimiter=',')

Comment: can you post sample of two rows

Comment: 12....
345..
6789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
for col in A.columns:
    A[col].to_csv('A_'+col+'.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

and you will end up with one txt file per column.