# Remove non-numeric in df column with different datatypes

Tags: python, string, dataframe, integer, substring

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Id  Volume
1   350 L
2   250.0
3   150//
4   250 L
```

i want to remove the non-numeric in Volume column. The desire output is:

```
Id  Volume
1   350
2   250
3   150
4   250
```

I've tried to use `df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)` but it turns the '250.0' and '150//' value become nan.

I've also tried to use `df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].str[:3]` but it also turns the '250.0' and '150//' value become nan.

I also tried to change the column dtypes to string, but it didn't work. It's still in object datatype.

Comment: Try: `df['Volume'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)')`

Comment: @enke it still turns the '250.0' and '150//' value become nan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work : `df['Volumne'] = df['Volume'].str.replace(r'[^0-9.]', '')`

Comment: this still turns the '250.0' and '150//' value become nan.

Comment: How did you try to change the datatype, the error might be because the object datatype needs to be converted to string. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231592/pandas-change-data-type-of-series-to-string)